# Using post with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this route:

```
avatar_add_from_collection POST   /avatars/:avatar_id/add_from_collection(.:format)            {:action=>"add_from_collection", :controller=>"avatars"}
```

and I am trying to create a link using link_to that uses post. The reason I need to do that is because (apparently) you can't put an image on a button using button_to.

```
<%= link_to inline_avatar(avatar.fetch_avatar_image(:thumb)), add_from_collection_avatar_path(avatar),:method=>:post%>
```

brings up

```
No route matches "/avatars/3/add_from_collection"
```

If I change the routes file to make this a GET it works just fine.

The link_to looks like

```
link_to inline_avatar(avatar.fetch_avatar_image(:thumb)), avatar_add_from_collection_path(avatar),:method=>:post
```

EDIT:

```
Jade::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :avatar_categories do
    delete :remove_item
  end

  resources :avatars do
    member do
     post 'add_from_collection', :on=>:member
    end
  end

  resources :categories,:addresses,:calendars,:topics,:profile,:news,:account_setting
  resources :boards do
    member do
      get :move
      post :move_category
    end
  end

  post 'avatars/display_collection'
  get "user/index"
  get 'login/index'
  get 'login/new'
  post 'login/create'
  post 'login/authenticate'
  get 'login/forgot_password'
  put 'login/reset_password'
  get 'login/logout' #post?
  get 'admin/index'
  get 'admin/app_settings'
  get 'admin/user_settings'
  get 'admin/avatars'
  post 'admin/avatar_upload'
  post 'admin/update_app_settings'
  get 'news_configurations/index'
  put 'news_configurations/update'
  get 'message_board_configurations/index'
  put 'message_board_configurations/update'
  get 'profile_settings/edit'
  post 'profile_settings/update'

  resources :posts do
    get :new,:edit
    post :create,:update,:destroy
  end

  match '/login' => 'login#index', :as => 'login'
  match '/admin' => 'admin#index', :as => 'admin'

  resources :login do
    get :index
    post :authenticate,:logout
  end
root :to => "news#index"

end
```

Comment: I did avatar_add_from_collection POST   /avatars/:avatar_id/add_from_collection(.:format)            {:action=>"add_from_collection", :controller=>"avatars"} generated from resources :avatars do
      post 'add_from_collection'
  end

Comment: you should specify `:as` option

Comment: Your second code snippet is the same as the first. Did you not paste it in correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :avatars do 
  member do
    post 'add_from_collection'
  end
end
```

or

```
resources :avatars do 
  post 'add_from_collection', :on => :member
end
```

**EDIT**

This is wrong

```
resources :avatars do
  member do
   post 'add_from_collection', :on=>:member
  end
end
```

use this

```
resources :avatars do
  post :add_from_collection, :on=>:member
end
```

But looks like this won't help

Comment: That actually made it worse, as button_to doesn't work with either of those,and the same no route error with the link_to

Comment: show how you are trying to do it. post sources. post error. more information

Comment: Same errors as I posted in the original post. The sources are the same except the path changed to add_from_collection_avatar. The reason the button_to broke was because :avatar_id changed to :id using a member block

Comment: <a href="/avatars/2/add_from_collection" data-method="post" rel="nofollow"><script>document.write('<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhSwBLAP...=\n">');</script></a>

Comment: I am having similar issues with link_to.. Seems the way around it is to use button_to..